# How to import tsx into a SPFx extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, tsx

I have just started my first SharePoint project and cannot figure out how to use my React components in my extension. Here are the relevant files.

Navbar.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
export const Navbar = props => <div>Hello world</div>;
```

ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizer.tsx:

```
import { override } from "@microsoft/decorators";
import { Log } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer,
  PlaceholderContent,
  PlaceholderName
} from "@microsoft/sp-application-base";
import { Dialog } from "@microsoft/sp-dialog";

import * as strings from "ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizerStrings";

import styles from "./AppCustomizer.module.scss";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";

import * as Components from "./components";
import Navbar = Components.Navbar;

const LOG_SOURCE: string = "ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizer";

/**
 * If your command set uses the ClientSideComponentProperties JSON input,
 * it will be deserialized into the BaseExtension.properties object.
 * You can define an interface to describe it.
 */

export interface IReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizerProperties {}

/** A Custom Action which can be run during execution of a Client Side Application */
export default class ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizer extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<
  IReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizerProperties
> {
  private _onDispose(): void {
    console.log("No place holder.");
  }
  private _topPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;
  private _renderPlaceHolders(): void {
    if (!this._topPlaceholder) {
      this._topPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
        PlaceholderName.Top,
        { onDispose: this._onDispose }
      );

      if (!this._topPlaceholder) {
        return;
      }

      if (this.properties) {
        const Nav = Navbar(null);

        if (this._topPlaceholder.domElement) {
          this._topPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = `
            <div class="${styles.app}">
              <div class="ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${
                styles.top
              }">
               ${Nav}
               ${Navbar}
               <div>Hello</div>
              <Navbar/>
              </div>
            </div>`;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

    // Added to handle possible changes on the existence of placeholders.
    this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(
      this,
      this._renderPlaceHolders
    );

    // Call render method for generating the HTML elements.
    this._renderPlaceHolders();
    return Promise.resolve<void>();
  }
}
```

components:

```
export * from "./Navbar";
```

My goal is to use my react component as a navigation bar, however I cannot manage to combine tsx and ts in this context.

I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions

Outside of these files, the only modifications I made were to add a components folder, with the component and index you see above.

Please help me solve this challenge.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "cannot manage to combine tsx and ts." Are you getting a compiler error? Are you not sure how to import the tsx file into a ts file? Something else?

Comment: Hello @ecraig12345, As the title reads, I cannot import import tsx into a SPFx extension. Which is a ts file, as I followed the cited guide.
 There is no compiler error, therefore there is no error to cite. Can I give you more info to help? Have you successfully built a SharePoint extension before? Do you know what I am talking about? Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this for a few hours, I have found the solution. I was coming at this the wrong way, I needed to use ReactDOM to insert my TSX components. Afterward it was normal React development. No need to try to insert elements in some fancy way as I was doing before.

Here is the working code.

**ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizer.ts**:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { override } from "@microsoft/decorators";
import { Log } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer,
  PlaceholderContent,
  PlaceholderName
} from "@microsoft/sp-application-base";

import { Dialog } from "@microsoft/sp-dialog";

import * as strings from "ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizerStrings";

import styles from "./AppCustomizer.module.scss";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";

import Navbar, { INavbarProps } from "./components/Navbar";

const LOG_SOURCE: string = "ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizer";

export interface IReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizerProperties {}

export default class ReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizer extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<
  IReactSharePointNavbarApplicationCustomizerProperties
> {
  private _onDispose(): void {}

  private onRender(): void {
    const header: PlaceholderContent = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
      PlaceholderName.Top,
      {
        onDispose: this._onDispose
      }
    );
    if (!header) {
      Log.error(LOG_SOURCE, new Error("Could not find placeholder PageHeader"));
      return;
    }

    const elem: React.ReactElement<INavbarProps> = React.createElement(Navbar);
    ReactDOM.render(elem, header.domElement);
  }

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.onRender();
    return Promise.resolve<void>();
  }
}
```

**Navbar.tsx**:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./Navbar.module.scss";

import NavbarItem from "../NavbarItem";

export interface INavbarProps {}

export default class Navbar extends React.Component<INavbarProps> {
  constructor(props: INavbarProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div className={"ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white " + styles.nav}>
        Hello world
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the components.ts export file was unnecessary. And I am sure other code may still be useless in these examples.

I found that importing tsx components into other tsx components works like normal React imports. Just import and insert as an element.